# Change Cognito User Status to MFA_SETUP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible via the cognito API to change a users status to MFA_SETUP programatically on a user pool which has mfa set to optional?

Our use case is we setup users with different groups and want to enforce mfa only on our admin group. From what gather from the documentation the MFA_SETUP status will send a challenge to the user to setup mfa on login but I'm not sure if that is only possible if mfa is required on the user pool. If there is another way to force a user to setup mfa while keeping the pool to be mfa optional that would also be fine. We are also not using the hosted ui and are using the cognito server side authentication flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your user pool MFA setting is set to **optional**, Cognito won't respond with the MFA setup challenge automatically. You need to *explicitly* make the call to setup MFA from your client for Cognito to respond with the appropriate challenge to set up authenticator based MFA.

Using the AWS SDK, the method to set up MFA for a user is AssociateSoftwareToken, which which will respond with the secret code you could show as a QR code to set up the user's MFA. Here is the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateSoftwareToken.html) for this call.

After your user verifies the code, they will get the "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA" challenge when they attempt to log in.
Follow [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-totp.html#totp-mfa-set-up-api) if you still need help with the remaining steps to verify and authenticate the MFA code.

**TIP:** Since this call requires a valid session and access token, you need to have authenticated your user first.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related code example in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). You will not find this code in the Service Guide.

This code shows you how to handle **MFA_SETUP** status, and so on. By going through this in the programming language you are using (the Code Lib provides different programming languagues), you will gain a better understanding of working with this AWS Service and the corresponding API.

The use case shows how to:

1. Sign up a user with a user name, password, and email address.
2. Confirm the user from a code sent in email.
3. Set up multi-factor authentication by associating an MFA application with the user.
4. Sign in by using a password and an MFA code.

Here is the link.

[Sign up a user with an Amazon Cognito user pool that requires MFA using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cognito-identity-provider_example_cognito-identity-provider_Scenario_SignUpUserWithMfa_section.html)

**TIP**: To set up the required user pool, run the AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) script provided in this GitHub repo at [resources/cdk/cognito_scenario_user_pool_with_mfa](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/resources/cdk/cognito_scenario_user_pool_with_mfa).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but I think that code example is assuming that the user pool has mfa set to required which mine is set to optional but only want to enforce MFA_SETUP conditionally.

Comment: You are - and that is why i used the term related code example (not an exact match). However, I think you will still gain a better understanding here looking at it. You are correct too - the user pool that the CDK creates has mfa.

Comment: I would experiment with this as well. Once you run the CDK and create the user pool, set the user pool to match your settings and go through the code.

Comment: The problem i've been having is i've already created the pool. I can create a new user with adminCreateUser which creats the user and conformation email but at the point of initiateauth (adminInitiateAuth in my case) Its just a noraml login without mfa and I cant seem to set a user attribute to change that. I'm struggling to see if its possible

Comment: I've tried setting adminUpdateUserAttributes with preferred_mfa_setting but that errors because no software token was associated and same with AdminSetUserMfaPreferenceRequest

Comment: I think that the user pool has to be setup the same way as shown in that example. I have never tried running this without that given user pool. I am asking others on my team to look here and provide thoughts